# Why the de particle and not ni here?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-で

駅で掃除ロボットがある wouldnt it make sense to use "ni" here since there is no action taking place?

Comment: Please show us the original context (do not try to explain it yourself). Was this the entire sentence?

Comment: 日本に昨日帰って来て今日ここにくる前に駅に行ったんですけどなんかそこで掃除ロボットがいたんですよ the context is from "Let's learn japanese from small talk!" Ep 31 10:08

Comment: It says そこで with そこ referring to 駅. It's not the same thing as saying 駅で in that sentence.

Comment: @sundowner How are そこで and 駅で different in terms of the use of で instead of saying say そこに or 駅に?

Comment: @A.Ellett Can't explain very well, but in the whole sentence, そこで works partially like *then/there* and sounds ok because of it.  駅でロボットがいた **alone** doesn't sound completely right. 駅に is better. I suppose it is a case where judging from standalone sentences is difficult.

Comment: @sundowner I see.  I was thinking that might be where you were coming from, but I wasn't sure.  Thank you for spelling out what you did.  It was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is action.  A robot vacuum cleaner is constantly moving around all day cleaning up whatever it comes across.

My sense is that with に it would sound like the robot is not being used and perhaps forgotten about stored away in some corner of the station.

That just doesn't sound as interesting as saying that there is a robot there constantly cleaning thes tation.